# Return list of all active observers in a Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

While using `browser()` with an active Shiny app, I can get a vector of all the inputs created using:
`reactiveValuesToList(input) %>% names()`

I can also get a vector of all the output names created using:
`outputOptions(output) %>% names()`

But what about if I want to get a list/vector of all the active observers?
Say make an actionButton with id = **mybutton1**, it will appear in the list of all inputs.
Now, I create an observer for mybutton1:

```
observeEvent(input$mybutton1, {
     print("Button clicked!")
})
```

This observer is now created, right?
Is there a way I can access the list of observers with something like `obs$names` or `getObs()` ? (I'm making these up).
If there is, can I simply get the name of an observer to destroy it? `rm(obs$mybutton1)` or `destroy(obs$mybutton1)`.

Comment: You mean you create the observer with **browser**?

Comment: No, I simply meant that whilst browsing inside the environment of a running app, to check active inputs I can use reactiveValuesToList(input) - simply wondering if the same is possible for observers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An observer has the class `Observer`, and you can assign an observer to a variable:

```
library(shiny)

values <- reactiveValues(A = 1)

obsB <- observe({
  print(values$A + 1)
})
obsC <- observe({
  print(values$A * 2)
})
```

Then you can get the names of all variables storing an observer as follows:

```
Filter(function(x) inherits(get(x), "Observer"), ls())
# "obsB" "obsC"
```

An observer is also a `R6` object, and it has a method `destroy()`:

```
obsB$destroy()
```

But destroying an observer does not remove it:

```
Filter(function(x) inherits(get(x), "Observer"), ls())
# "obsB" "obsC"
```

It will not observe anymore, that's all. So you have to use `rm` if needed.

Comment: Thanks, that is a very good workaround.